# Workaround for J2ME Hessian limitations?

Tags: java, interop, java-me, hessian

The official J2ME implementation of Hessian seems to have serious limitations : complex objects are not supported.
 This limitation is not mentioned anywhere on the online documentation, but if you google "hessian j2me" you will find posts about this problem. No solutions found with google though. 
Does anyone have a solution for this problem ? Is there an alternate implementation of Hessian for J2ME ? 
I would like to avoid getting strings from Hessian and then do some JSON/XML parsing to get objects...

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat confusing as a Hessian is a matrix of mixed second partial derivatives, and a library that couldn't handle complex numbers would indeed be a problem.

Why'd they have to reuse a well-established name with other meanings?